# SSAS ProcessUpdate, Rigid Relationships and member deletions

Tags: multidimensional-array, ssas

I am having issues during a ProcessUpdate on a SSAS dimension.  Here is, albeit simplified, how the dimension is set up:

In a "Reservation" dimension, I have my DimensionKey attribute set to be the reservation itslef (Key attribute: ReservationKey, Name Attribute: Reservation Code).  To that member is attached (flexible Relationship) a "ReservationAgent" Member (Key: ReservationAgentCode, Name: ReservationAgentName) and to the "ReservationAgent" member, I have "ReservationAgentCode" member which is related by a rigid Relationship to the "Reservation Agent Name".

Now I'm sure you'd agree with me that it is impossible for the "ReservationAgent" to suddenly relate to a different "ReservationAgentCode" since the key of both attributes is the SQL column "ReservationAgentCode".

I have come in a situation where all Reservations of a given ReservationAgentCode were moved to a different ReservationAgentCode. so in essence, the old ReservationAgentCode is now non-existent. Remember here that "Reservation" and "ReservationAgentCode" Relationship is flexible.

Upon doing a ProcessUpdate on the dimension, SSAS gives me an error about not being able to change a rigid relationship between "ReservationAgent" and "ReservationAgentCode".

Since both the "ReservationAgent" and "ReservationAgentCode" members are effectively new, there is no movement of the old "ReservationAgent" to a different "ReservationAgentCode". Only the old members need to be deleted in a sense.

Has anyone come to that kind of situation?  Is it something i'm not quite understanding correctly? To me it seems like a glitch/bug but before open a connect ticket at MS, i'd like to have feedback from the experts here.

Let me know if you need more info and I could also elaborate a quick solution demonstrating my issue if needed.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bug, David.

Process Update removes the old ReservationAgentCode member from dimension (since on stage of members detecting doesn't see it in source). Server won't allow this deletion, since we have rigid relation later ("rigid attribute relationship is one where the member relationships are guaranteed to be fixed" - performance guide 2008 r2).

By the way, what is the benefit of using rigid relations there (performance / process time / both)?